# Possible to use @RepositoryRestResource with @PathVariable instead of @Param?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I have a RestRepositoryResource which is working properly.  However, I would prefer to structure URLs using path variables instead of query parameters.  The goal would be this:

```
http://localhost/persons/findByLastName/Smith/
```

instead of this:

```
http://localhost/persons/findByLastName?lastName=Smith
```

I have played around with various annotations but not achieved this using RestRepositoryResource.  Is this possible or does this have to be done with a Controller resource mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Spring data repositories don't support the @PathVariable annotation right now. However a simple workaround for this problem might be to use [URLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/guide.html) internally re-route the request for `http://localhost/persons/findByLastName/Smith/` to `http://localhost/persons/findByLastName?lastName=Smith` without the user noticing.